# add 4 additional columns to a +60col table or spin them off to a new one?

Tags: mysql

I have to add 4 more columns to each product, which only required once per product.
The product table is already at over 60 columns.
is it much more of a hit to add these to the products table, or, even though there is only one set of ratings per table, is it better to put them in their own table?

I'm stuffing these into an existing cart system and, for me, tagging the columns to the existing table would make the php work easier.

Thanks for you opinions!

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: My bet is that your database isn't normalized and you actually need less than 60 columns inside that table. Can you please show us the column definition and some sample data?

Comment: Normalisation is nearly always the enemy of speed.

Comment: lol, really? and what's the price of the "speed" you'd gain?

Comment: HDD space, normally. Denormalisation can lead to huge speed increases, especially if the alternative is multiple joins. Obviously you have to make sure you code everything correctly so you don't get mismatched data, but hey - that's what we're for =]

Comment: actually, the database is fairly normalized.  There are only a couple column groups that could be moved over to their own table.  There are already multiple joins occurring through the code.

Comment: I bit the bullet and made a ratings table.  The main hassle I have now is adding them during a bulk product upload.  I've already worked out the joins; using left, as not all of the products have ratings added.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, adding more columns will make it slower.

You will get fewer rows per page, so you will need to read more data from the disk, and less will be cached.

How much slower is hard to tell, though - whether it's faster to do a join in the long run is something you'll have to test for.